# Скачивание большого объёма картинок

Tags: php, парсер, vps, изображения

Есть список ссылок на ~300-400к картинок, картинки разного размера. Предположим, что в среднем картинка весит 1мб.
Как выкачать такой большой объём картинок? Может есть какие-то готовые решения/библиотеки для парсинга? ЯП: предпочтительно PHP. И какие vps можете посоветовать, где дают подобный объём за разумные деньги?

Comment: а сколько по Вашему *разумные деньги* ?

Comment: Ну, с учётом такого требования до 3-5 т.р. в месяц. Но я готов рассмотреть разные варианты, дешёвые и дорогие.

Comment: Не совсем ясно в чем вопрос: как качать на PHP? Как скачать кучу файлов по списку? Где добыть дискового пространства?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Геморройный и не быстрый, но точно самый дешевый способ, всего 99 рублей будет стоить (дешевле только самолично написать скрипт парсинга и запускать его на своем собственном компьютере):

1) берем весь список ссылок на картинки (который 300-400к штук), разбиваем его на куски по 5к ссылок, сохраняем каждый кусок построчно в отдельный файл (html/txt без разницы), например, так (http:// или https:// в начале строк обязательно указывать в вашем случае):

```
http://picdomain.ru/pic1.jpg
http://picdomain.ru/pic2.gif
http://picdomain.ru/picN.jpg
```

2) заливаем полученные файлы с урлами картинок куда-нибудь, чтобы они стали доступны в интернете по адресу, например:

> domen.ru/file1.txt; 
>   domen.ru/file2.txt; 
>   и т.д.;

3) покупаем PRO на месяц за 99 рублей в парсере картинок [здесь](http://backlinks-checker.dimax.biz/tools/parser_kartinok.php).

4) вбиваем по 1 урлу domen.ru/file1.txt в парсер (хоть там и можно по 10 урлов сразу задавать, не стоит этого делать, потому что даже 5к картинок парситься будут долго), сохраняем полученный архив с картинками, затем вбиваем в парсер адрес следующего файла со ссылками на картинки (domen.ru/file2.txt) и т.д., пока не сохраните все, что надо :)

Comment: а не реклама ли это

Comment: Даже если это и реклама, то вполне себе хороший ответ! Вот что-то типа такого мне и надо. Изучу этот способ, спасибо!

Comment: Etki, вы меня раскусили, конечно, это реклама))Я ну очень хотел бы заработать 99 рублей, вручив готовую инструкцию человеку, как загрузить сервис работой по уши и 400 гигов трафик

Comment: Упс, я прошу прощения, не ожидал, что предыдущий коммент отправится, когда я нажму Enter (а я лишь хотел новую строку сделать) и его нельзя будет отредактировать или удалить. В общем, очевидно, что предыдущий комментарий оказался слегка недописан, хотя суть, наверное, ясна)

Answer (score 0):

Качать на php просто:

```
$folder = 'myfolder';
$filename = 'newpic';
$url = 'http://site.ru/img.jpg';
$tmp = file_get_contents($url);
file_put_contents($folder.$filename.'.jpg', $tmp);
```

А по поводу серверов - возьмите на hetzer там недорого